# How to handle validations for corrupted data on update?

Tags: mongodb, go

I have thousands of data, some of which are older and collection validations have changed so now when I want to update the old data I get `document validation failed`.

My first approach was to find a way to ignore validation when updating but I don't know how to do it and I'm also not sure if it's the best way.

Is it a good approach to ignore validations when updating and if so, how to achieve it?

What i've tried:

```
    filter := bson.M{"status": models.TICKET_STATUS_ACTIVE, "expire_at": bson.M{"$lte": time.Now()}}
    update := bson.D{{"$set", bson.M{"status": models.TICKET_STATUS_EXPIRED}}}

    updatedRows, err := collection.UpdateMany(dbCtx, filter, update)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("update error ", err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("updated rows: ", updatedRows)
```

alternative solutions are aprreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `SetBypassDocumentValidation` method which you can set in update options and if is set to `true`, it ignores validations when updating.

E.g:

```
    updatedRows, err := collection.UpdateMany(dbCtx, filter, update, options.Update().SetBypassDocumentValidation(true))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("update error ", err)
        return
    }
```